# Are there invalid floating point states/values?

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754, low-level

I know that NaN and various other special cases exist. But are there other unused binary values which are completely invalid?

For example, IEEE 754 *does* allow -0. But if it didn't, then the binary value `10000000000000000000000000000000` would be invalid. Are there other edge cases that are unhandled?

Comment: Nope. Normal numbers, subnormal numbers, +-Inf, +-Zero, and NaN:s make up the entire IEEE-754 coding space.

Answer (score 4):

IEEE-754 binary and decimal interchange formats do not have any undefined bit patterns. (For decimal, the Encodings section in IEEE 754-2008 clause 3.5.2 specifies values [including NaN “values”] for all bit strings. Some of the bit strings are designated as non-canonical, but all have defined values.)

Intel’s “double extended-precision” format does have undefined bit patterns. *Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual*, December 2017, 8.2.2 “Unsupported Double Extended-Precision Floating-Point Encodings and Pseudo-Denormals” says:

> The double extended-precision floating-point format permits many encodings that do not fall into any of the categories shown in Table 4-3. Table 8-3 shows these unsupported encodings. Some of these encodings were supported by the Intel 287 math coprocessor; however, most of them are not supported by the Intel 387 math coprocessor and later IA-32 processors. These encodings are no longer supported due to changes made in the final version of IEEE Standard 754 that eliminated these encodings.
>
> Specifically, the categories of encodings formerly known as pseudo-NaNs, pseudo-infinities, and un-normal numbers are not supported and should not be used as operand values. The Intel 387 math coprocessor and later IA-32 processors generate an invalid-operation exception when these encodings are encountered as operands.
>
> …

Table 8-3 shows the undefined patterns all have a zero in the integer bit (the leading bit of the significand, which is stored explicitly in a dedicated “integer” one-bit field in Intel’s format) and a non-zero exponent field. When the exponent field is all ones, these are pseudo-NaNs (if the fraction field is non-zero) or pseudo-infinities (if the fraction field is zero). When the exponent field is neither all ones (nor all zeros), these are unnormals.

(When the integer bit is zero and the exponent field is all zeros, the number is an ordinary subnormal; the zero integer bit correctly matches the zero implied by the exponent field.)

Other vendors and parties may of course also have their own formats with undefined bit patterns.

Comment: Perhaps worth noting that while the decimal interchange formats don't have invalid bit patterns, they _do_ have some non-canonical bit patterns (though exactly which bit patterns are non-canonical depends on whether the significand uses binary encoding or decimal encoding), and there's an explicit mapping from non-canonical bit patterns to canonical equivalents. _Most_ operations are specified to accept non-canonical bit-patterns but only emit canonical bit patterns. (Some operations, like `copySign` and friends, _can_ produce non-canonical results for non-canonical inputs.)

Comment: @MarkDickinson: Thanks. I just got some time to read the decimal Encodings section, and it does look to me like each bit string is specified to have some value, even though some bit strings are non-canonical. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In 80 bit extended, there are "unnormalised" numbers. In that format, the complete mantissa is stored, including the leading 1 bit. If that bit isn't set, that's an "unnormalised" number which shouldn't happen. At the extreme, you could have a zero (mantissa all bits zero) with a large exponent.

Still, that will be handled correctly. I wouldn't be surprised if you got a hardware exception that translates this unusual format to a normalised or denormalised number. And 80 bit extended is not present on some processors.

Apart from that, everything is allowed. Obviously you have "signalling NaNs" which are *supposed* to create some signal if you use them, but that's as intended. And uninitialised memory can have side effects due to your compiler (uninitialised memory is always undefined behaviour), that's the same as with unsigned int, for example. But there is no bit pattern where that bit pattern would cause you trouble.

Comment: *Still, that will be handled correctly.* - By what?  Eric's answer cites documentation saying that 387 HW (and modern CPUs that are compatible with it) will treated non-normalized 80-bit floats (other than subnormals) as invalid, raising the FP-invalid exception.  (So producing a NaN output or trapping, depending on whether FP exceptions are masked.)